# Git Setup on RHEL

Tags: git

This may be chew up question. But I am getting confused for bits and pieces. 
So here we go, I have org based personal repo which I like to clone it and work on it (only test branch).

I have not created local branch. I have setup secure token access already.

my intended workflow as follow:

- Clone existing repo with branch TEST
- Work on TEST branch locally on RHEL
- Make Changes and push it to remote branch

Now I know I can clone repo with branch paramter. Its option 2 and 3 I am not sure what commands I have to use. There are lot of commands avaialble but not sure which one?

Comment: how is RHEL relevant to the question? what is org based repo?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git for beginners: The definitive practical guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide)

Comment: @Pbd org based repo means github.google.com etc.

 i am just not sure how to operate this workflow at command level as I always used Git Desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out following steps.

1) You need to clone your repo first.

```
git clone <repo>
```

2) Move to the branch of interest. In git, this is called checkout.

```
git checkout <branch>
```

3) After you have made your changes, you need to push those changes back to remote repo.

```
git push origin <branch>
```